# How to Update a exactly sheet tab row with a value from a imported data in another tab in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have this tab in Google spreadsheet 
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14ZBff8R6brLYWtfv70V-tyG0HE-sX_ejySvplQqZftM/edit#gid=1450402909]

Sheet *All Tasks*, *Candice Tasks*, *Others People Tasks*

At Sheet *All Tasks*  I have a column to add the status from my projects.

Columns *date*, *task*, *Comment*, *status*

each row is a different task and assigned to a different person.

The column Status Has (Complete, In Progress).

I'm using this to import only my tasks to *Candice Tasks*
`=QUERY( ImportRange( "Key", "All Tasks!A3:I1000" ) , "where Col3 = 'Candice Tasks' order by Col2 desc")`

But I need some way to update the status in Candice Tasks and automatically updates the cell in the column status at my Sheet *All Tasks* in the same task row I altered at my sheet.

Any Help Please?

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question with the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **'All Tasks'!A3** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 INDIRECT("Candice!A4:M"&COUNTA(Candice!B4:B)+3); 
 INDIRECT("Dhruv!A4:M"&COUNTA(Dhruv!B4:B)+3)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hello, thank you, but i got this error  #REF! Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in b3...

Comment: you need to delete everything in **B3:M** range so that arrayformula could roll out the data

Comment: from b column, row 4 until M column?

Comment: from B3 to M6 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EfNU.png

Comment: I deleted, but when I change the status from one row in Candice, everything disappears in the Sheet and shows the row 2 from All Tasks

Comment: @CandiceHorie https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DUtor4OZRtSOEo-3EmIOapSBgIGIuG2Wjr9-Ur_PIa8/edit#gid=1450402909

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!